# Can I say this "your ... is impressive" to my professor?

Tags: expressions, formality, letter-writing

I am writing an email request for a reference letter to one of my professors. I would like to address her kindness in my email because she was always very patient when I asked her questions.

My question is 'Can I write something like "Your gracious and kindness is impressive"?' My concern is, 'Should the word "impressive" be only used when speaking to an academic subordinate?' When speaking to an academic superior, for example my professor, does the word "impressive" feel disrespectful?

This is probably a stupid question because English is not my native language, but I really do not want to take the risk of offending my professor.

Thanks!

Comment: You are right to be a little dubious about telling your professor that her kindness is impressive. In my opinion it would be better to simply thank her for her kindness and graciousness during your course of studies. Other responders to your question may have  alternative suggestions. In any case, it needs to be _graciousness_ not _gracious_. _Gracious_ is an adjective. And it should be _are_ not _is_ impressive. (It is a not a stupid question!)

Comment: This is more a cultural matter: **1** Effusive praise is not given to superiors and can even be embarrassing among equals. English (particularly British English) tends to be restrained. **2** Any form of praise when asking for a favour is also questionable and should be avoided because it is seen as trying to influence the person to give a positive response.

Comment: If you chose ***impressive*** because you (mistakenly) thought it could carry the sense of ***made an impression on me***, I suggest you switch to [***touching***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/touching) - *Arousing feelings of sympathy **or gratitude**.* But this isn't really to do with being "respectful" - it's just basic vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a stupid question; those things have to be learned, as anything else. The problem concerning them is that they do not make the object of regular courses and that you learn them mostly as you go along.

What you feel about your professor is quite understandable but the terms you envisage to use to express that to her are for the least very unusual, not to say extravagant in the context of addressing her. The adjective "gracious" is in no way acceptable here; *if* in the end you were to mention such a characteristic as "grace" or "graciousness", as this latter seems more appropriate, you'd have to use "Your graciousness and kindness…", because "gracious" is only an adjective.
A second point to understand is the fact that academic superiors are not to be communicated assessments  on the level of  their character in public or otherwise, be those ever so flattering, nor to be praised for their academic achievements too enthusiastically by their pupils. You might be impressed and there is nothing wrong with saying that to your schoolmates and other persons but you might make your professor a little ill at ease. In any case, this way of addressing academic superiors is not used. Instead of writing that you are impressed you may mention the effect that this graciousness and this kindness  shown to you are something that you are grateful for; you may not say that you are pleased with it, but you may be thankful for it; one way to do that would be to write "I'm thankful for the graciousness and kindness that you've shown to me."

Comment: You are clearly a thoughtful and reflective person, and I suspect you almost knew the answer before you questioned us. I agree with and have marked up Shoe and LPH. It is presumptuous to express a general opinion about character. It is acceptable and far better to express appreciation of specific things such as patience in solving problem A, generosity in sharing an idea B, help in introducing person C ...

Comment: @Anton Very apparently your comment goes under the OP's post.

Comment: Point taken. Despite my recent enthusiasm for this site I still make procedural mistakes. I suspect that, like the dog who died just as it had been trained to do without food, so will I die just as I am perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @Anton Never say die!